# How to place data labels out side the donut chart with lines using jqplot?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jqplot

If the area is very small then the labels are getting overlapped in the donut chart.
How to place the data labels outside the donut chart with lines.
Currently I am able to draw the labels inside the chart. Find the sample code from here:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var s1 = [['a',6], ['b',8], ['c',14], ['d',20]];

  var plot3 = $.jqplot('chart4', [s1], {
    seriesDefaults: {
      // make this a donut chart.
      renderer:$.jqplot.DonutRenderer,
      rendererOptions:{
        // Donut's can be cut into slices like pies.
        sliceMargin: 3,
        // Pies and donuts can start at any arbitrary angle.
        startAngle: -90,
        showDataLabels: true,
        // By default, data labels show the percentage of the donut/pie.
        // You can show the data 'value' or data 'label' instead.
        dataLabels: 'value'
      }
    }
  });
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Aaradhana/9gXc3/)

This is my expected output:

[image]

Helps much appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, what you need to set is:

```
dataLabelPositionFactor: 2
```

Please see jsFiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/9gXc3/1/

And further info here:

http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/plugins/jqplot-donutRenderer-js.html

**Update**

I'd also set the padding too to avoid overlap i.e.

```
padding: 50
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9gXc3/3/

Comment: I tried it using dataLabelPositionFactor attribute.
But for the worst case scenario, I need to place the labels outside the chart with lines.
Update the dat a in the fiddle using these values.
 var s1 = [['a',50], ['b',1], ['c',1], ['d',48]];
For this case it is overlapping. Check this http://jsfiddle.net/9gXc3/5/

Comment: I think this might solve the line issue for you...  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20137852/how-to-add-jqplot-pie-chart-labels-with-lines Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Use, dataLabelPositionFactor: 1.2, inside rendererOptions.

Below is an example I used in a project:

rendererOptions: {
padding: 8,
showDataLabels: true,
dataLabels: percentage,
dataLabelFormatString: '%s%%',
diameter: 300,
dataLabelPositionFactor: 1.1,
sliceMargin: 4,
startAngle: -90,
color: '#DCDCDC'
}